# Permission management by tab removal using SQL

Tags: c#, sql, tabs, permissions

I need an idea. I have an app, a winform having multiple tabs in it. There are a bunch of people using it, but none of them needs to use all the tabs, just a couple of them. I've reached a point where it's hard to handle from the source code, so I need a solution to easily manage the permissions. The best would be to use an SQL table for this as I also have to provide for another guy the possibility to modify the rights. I think it would be fine to simply remove the tabs by creating an sql table like this, and at the program startup simply query something like this:

```
select tabid from table where loggedinuser = 0
```

and then just loop through the result and remove all of them

```
foreach(tabid in tabids)
{
    tabControl1.TabPages.RemoveByKey(tabid);
}
```

table:

```
+----------+----------+-------+-------+-------+
| tabid    | name     | user1 | user2 | user3 |
+----------+----------+-------+-------+-------+
| tabPage1 | project1 | 0     | 1     | 0     |
+----------+----------+-------+-------+-------+
| tabPage2 | project2 | 1     | 0     | 1     |
+----------+----------+-------+-------+-------+
| tabPage3 | project3 | 1     | 0     | 0     |
+----------+----------+-------+-------+-------+
```

However I somehow feel that this is not an elegant solution, especially because you have create a new column each time a new guy has to be added. Do you have any idea how to solve it?

Comment: Tabs won't change so often, users probably will. Put tabs in columns and keep one row per user. Or, better, use a single row for each entry (user, tab). You won't even need to insert all records (entry with 0 can be omitted)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is an issue of the database's design, and a basic one; perhaps you need to improve your understanding of SQL databases, particularly relationships and primary/foreign keys. You shouldn't add new columns but new rows.
You need a table for the users, one for the tabs and one to connect the two. Such as this:

```
User:
+---------+------+
| user_id | name |
+---------+------+
|       1 | John |
+---------+------+
|       2 | Jane |
+---------+------+

Tab:
+--------+----------+
| tab_id | title    |
+--------+----------+
|      1 | Articles |
+--------+----------+
|      2 | Products |
+--------+----------+

UserTab:
+---------+--------+---------+
| user_id | tab_id | enabled |
+---------+--------+---------+
|       1 |      1 |       1 |
+---------+--------+---------+
|       1 |      2 |       0 |
+---------+--------+---------+
|       2 |      1 |       0 |
+---------+--------+---------+
|       2 |      2 |       1 |
+---------+--------+---------+
```

In this example, John can only access Articles and Jane can only access Products.

You should get the ID of the current user and get the entries from UserTab, then remove the tabs that correspond to the IDs for which enabled=0.

You also should make a "default" choice for when the right combination of user and tab doesn't exist in the UserTab table: either display the tab by default or hide it by default.

Answer (score 1):

If you do it through SQL, a simple data model could be :

1. USER TABLE would have fields `user_id`,`username`,... all USER related fields you wish
2. ROLE TABLE would have fields `role_id`,`role_name`
3. USERROLE TABLE would have fields `f_user_id`,`f_role_id`(both foreign keys)

   Each record (line) in this table  links a user to a role, so a user can have many roles, and a role can be attribuated to many users. That's called a many-to-many relationship
4. ROLERIGHT TABLE would have fields `f_role_id`,`tabid`

   Each record (line) in this table links a role to a tab that this role has access to. That means if a role should access all tabs and you've got 10 tabs, you'll have 10 lines with the same role_id and a different tabid from 1 to 10. It is also a many-to-many relationship.

This is quite an usual database pattern for access right management I guess. Now what you have to do is define the several roles. And assign it to the different users. If a new user comes in and he should have the same rights as another user, you just have to assign him the same role(s) as the other user. Depending on complexity and the number of possible tabs/users combinations, you will or not have many roles with few rights, or a few roles with access to several tabs. The latter would probably be the case for a limited number of users, but the good thing is that you could easily scale up without changing the model, only the data.

Comment: Each user is pretty unique, so probably there is no need to create roles.

Comment: In that case, you could indeed easily drop the roles. The model suggested in the other answer by GeorgeT would be enough then. This will be even easier to implement now, but this is less future-proof. You're in the best place to evaluate your needs :-)